# Scraping a webpage with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, web-scraping, bots

I'm looking for a way to get all the sentences in 'lead'-tags from this webpage: http://taz.de/!p4633/c.xml
and put them into an array. Can a javascript program get information from the web like that?

for example, where it says

```
<lead>Sentence1 blablabla. sentence2 bla bla bla.</lead>
<headline>something else</headline>
<lead>sentence3 blablabla. sentence4 bla bla.</lead>
```

I'd like to get the strings like so:

```
var sentences = ["Sentence1 blablabla.", "sentence2 bla bla bla.", "sentence3 blablabla.", "sentence4 bla bla."];
```

The reason is that I want to make a twitterbot that answers with random sentences from this newspaper's website. I searched tutorials for webscraping, but I'm not familiar with node.js and couldn't get any of the other tools to work either, because I know so little about programming.

Comment: Sure you can, even so, the method and reach of said extraction depends on the platform the JS code is executed. Is it for Browser (client)-side? -or on the Server side (perhaps NodeJS) ?

Comment: This site is not for people to write free code for you. Show your code that almost/nearly works and then people will help. Show no code and people will stay silent, vote you down, or sometimes even close the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a javascript program get information from the web like that?

Yes.

You'll need to know about Node's [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html), particularly [`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback). Then you'll need an XML parser. There should be a bunch floating around in npm, choose any one. Get the XML, parse the XML, pick the pieces of data you want and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, I couln't get a real response from your webpage cause of firewall, but try this example code, and tell us:

```js
var fakeResponse = "<xml><lead>Sentence1 blablabla. sentence2 bla bla bla.</lead></xml>";


function processResponse(response) {
   
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml"); //important to use "text/xml"
  for (var i=0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lead").length; i++) {
    var html = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lead")[i].innerHTML;
    
    console.log("item " + i + "=>" + html);  
  }
  
  
}

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
      var responseData = this.responseText;
      
      responseData = fakeResponse; //delete This line, just for testing
      
        processResponse(responseData)
      
    }
    
};
var your_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"; //update with the url of your webservice     
xhttp.open("GET", your_url, true);
xhttp.send();
```